# How to define keys in evil mode command mode

Tags: key-bindings, evil

I'm trying to create a shortcut in command mode. Basically, by typing  `:bl`, I want it to execute `gud-break`. I tried the following

```
(evil-define-key 'insert c-mode-map (kbd ":bl") 'gud-break)
```

However, it complains that `bl` is not defined. Is there something wrong in my key binding?

Comment: You need to define an `ex` command.

Comment: You speak of "command mode" yet use insert state. This isn't going to work.

Comment: @Dan Thanks for the tip, I tried  (eval-after-load 'evil-ex
  '(evil-ex-define-cmd "bl" 'gud-break))   This works.

Comment: Time to answer your own question then!

Answer (score 1):

The following creates the relevant `evil` `ex` command:

```
(eval-after-load 'evil-ex
  '(evil-ex-define-cmd "bl" 'gud-break))
```